# FXCop Rule for "If X = Nothing" when X is a nullable integer

Tags: .net, vb.net, fxcop

```
1 Dim x as Integer? = Nothing  
2 If x = Nothing Then  
3     'this is what I think will happen   
4 Else  
5     'this is what really happens   
6 End If
```

The proper way to write that is "If x Is Nothing".

Is there a FXCop rule that checks for this? Or better yet, can someone show me how to write my own?

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another good resource for writing custom FxCop rules can be found here: [binarycoder](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to learn to write custom rules for FXCop is the forum [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vstscode/threads/) It involves writing an custom assembly to parse the code and check it.

Specifically you want to write a rule that says "Instead of using = nothing for a nullable type make sure you use hasvalue.